# UIWebView Strategy for Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Background: As of August 2019, Apple is now showing a deprecation warning when uploading apps to the App Store that include UIWebView-related code. As a result, all Cordova apps built for iOS receive this deprecation warning on upload.

We need to determine how Cordova as a project wants to proceed to solve this problem. There are pull requests already being opened that I'm quite concerned with end up breaking all existing Cordova apps, and I think we want to be more careful about that.

I've put together this document outlining some options for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The cordova inappbrowser was officially updated this week (v3.2.0). This solves the problem, but please read their guidelines to ensure your app will work as planned.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser